# I keep needing to use "mvn clean spring-boot:run" whenever there's small changes such as mappings to work properly. Any tips to fix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, frameworks

-Using Intellij Idea

-Automatically build project enabled in Compiler settings

-Tried invalidate caches on all options

-Using Ubuntu

-Tried deleting .idea folder and reopening

-Small changes would be changing the mapping i.e.

```
    @RequestMapping("/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("books", bookRepository.findAll());

        return "books/list"; //changes to template here i.e. return "books" instead
    }
```

Goal is to be able to Run the project from the IDE along with the changes without needing to use *mvn clean* in the terminal for every change

Update:
After moving on to a completely new project it's working as normal. However the old project still needs mvn clean spring-boot:run

Comment: Build with IntelliJ IDEA and run Spring Boot configuration, not via Maven, see https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps works for me

1. Please ensure to add the below dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

2. Go to
   File Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler -->enable **Build Project Automatically**
3. Go to Registry using
   Shift + Ctrl + A and type registry--> search for **compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running** and enable it using checkbox

In latest versions of intellij, option3 has been moved to advanced settings as  below

[image]

Comment: Tried 1 and 2 still doesn't work
3. There's no such automake in the registry on mine

Comment: Please check the adv settings tab. For more details refer to the above answer(updated)

Comment: Tried all with updated tips but no luck unfortunately. Even tried deleting and re-importing the whole project

Answer (score 0):

When all the solutions do not work, maybe you can try

`templateResolver.setCacheable(false);`

I faced this before cause thymeleaf cache, here is the full bean config

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    return templateResolver;
}
```